# Excel VBA Access to Sharepoint columns/metadata

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint-online

I am working on a spreadsheet that will reside in a document library on Sharepoint (365).  It has a content type with several columns defined, with data.

I can see the columns and the data in File --> Info --> Show All Properties.

I have the following function (which seems to work perfectly well in a different spreadsheet, though that one resides in a Sharepoint Document Set inside a Document Library, so the content type is Document Set which has a specific setting to allow columns to propagate down to Word/Excel.

```
Function sp_Meta(DocProp As String) As Variant

Application.Volatile

sp_Meta = ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties.GetItemByInternalName(DocProp).Value

End Function
```

I call it from the Excel spreadsheet in a cell with:

```
=@sp_Meta("AFF_x002d_Muncipality")
```

I got the internal name when I ran ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties.schemaXML, in which I can see the internal names for all my columns.

All I can get is #VALUE in the cell.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Thanks.

See above, outlines the steps.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it might be worth iterating over your document properties to check their names / internal IDs:

```
Dim prop as MetaProperty
For each prop in ThisWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties
  Debug.print prop.name, prop.id, prop.value
next
```